# How to upload file to a specific folder in S3 by Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sqs

How to upload a file to S3 into a specified folder?

The folder is created as `year/month/day/uuid/`

I used boto3 and created the folder in an S3 bucket.

```
def create_Object(bucket_name):   
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    now = datetime.now()
    year=now.strftime("%Y")
    month=now.strftime("%m")
    day=now.strftime("%d")
    uuidf=uuid.uuid4()
    obj_key=year+"/"+month+"/"+day+"/"+str(uuidf)
    print(obj_key)
    objRe=s3.upload_file(obj_key, bucket_name, "testfile.txt")
```

After the upload I need to send a message to SQS. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful -- in the `upload_file` call, you have the local file and the S3 Key mixed up.

Here's some code that will upload a given file to a `Y/M/D/random/` path, then send a message to SQS:

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
import uuid

LOCAL_FILE = 'file.txt'
BUCKET = 'my-bucket'
SQS_QUEUE = 'https://sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/123456789012/foo'

# Upload file to Y/M/D/random-id/filename
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
path = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d/") + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '/'
print(path)
response = s3_client.upload_file(LOCAL_FILE, BUCKET, path + LOCAL_FILE)

# Send a message to SQS
sqs_client = boto3.client('sqs', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
response = sqs_client.send_message(
    QueueUrl = SQS_QUEUE,
    MessageBody = 'New file is: ' + path + LOCAL_FILE
    )
```